# iTerm2 screen buffer not getting clear

Tags: bash, shell, vim, iterm2

I'm using bash as my shell and iTerm2 build 3.3.1 as my terminal emulator on Mac OS X 10.14.6 Whenever I use a type a long command, iTerm window overwrites my current line with the new symbols even though if I type proper command and run it, it runs successfully meaning, error is only in displaying command, not storing it. This also happens sometimes when I exit vim. Some of the buffer remains on screen, but my window is on shell, not on vim. This mainly happens when I use ctags and cscope. Screenshots of a long command and exiting vim are attached.

Please suggest some solution.

[image: long command in bash (shell)]

[image: exiting vim]

UPDATE 1:
I figured out that bash was misbehaving in case of commads because for color coding in `PS1`, I used `\e[....m` type of format. When I replaced with `\[...\]` then bash prompt issue got solved. I don't know why did it happen. Also issue about clearing shell buffer after exiting vim still happens (image 2).. any help regarding these would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I have figured out that it might be issue of custom PS1 which I'm using in my .bash_profile which goes like `export PS1="\e[40;0;31m[\[\033[36m\]\u \[\033[33;1m\]\w \e[0;32m\$git_branch\e[40;0;31m] \[\033[m\]$ "` (here `git_branch` is a custom function used to show my github branch). Can I add something to it so that new line uses `\r\n` to go to next line instead of just `\r`

Comment: This issue is happening due to presence of `\e...m` type of color formatting in PS1. Changing `\e....m` type to `\[.....\]` solves my bash issue. Altough not clear why this change is solving my problem

Comment: Hi @Chinmay, I had a similar issue related with a misspelling on my custom PS1 definition. Thank you so much! 